# How to enable check syntax PHP in visual studio code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I would like to ask you how can we activate check syntax on PHP file?

Because after searching on Google, we need to set user settings by adding:

```
 "php.validate.executablePath":"C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/php.exe"
```

But after testing a simple code with error, there is no signal

VS check syntax:
[image: VS check syntax]

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] *in the question itself* and not just a [picture of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: The message says that no problems were detected. Why do you think problems *should* be detected? The code compiles when I test it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013743/php-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no errors in your code example. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a
> semicolon at the end of each statement. **The closing tag of a block of**
> **PHP code automatically implies a semicolon**; you do not need to have a
> semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.

This

```
<?php 
echo 'test'
?>
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
<?php 
echo 'test'
;?>
```

So In PHP semicolon is multiple statements separator (a little bit different interpretation than in C)

**EDIT**

If you want to test error checking in Visual Studio - put a second echo statement, like :

[image]