# Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found in my codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone im new user in php with codeigniter as my framework, when im start to code, i got error can you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRWm0.png), i have tried this with adding configuration :

`// Points to the PHP executable.

"php.validate.executablePath": null,` in my setting.json from  [this solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013743/php-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code) but still no change. i hope everyone can help me. thanks